# Messy jQuery div to div append

Tags: jquery, html, append, fade

I am having issues with the jQuery div to div append on first load of a page.

Desired effect:
Essentially, just needs to have current div fade out, pause, then next one fade in.

Result:
Newly appended div jumps to top of div to be appended to, forcing the previous div down and looking unsightly. Almost as if the div is being faded in before the previous one has finished fading out, despite the `.delay()` function.

The original jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blurb > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
$('#blurb > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.delay(1000)
.next(1)
.fadeIn(1000)
.end(1)
.appendTo('#blurb');
},  5000);
});
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#blurb{
float:right;
text-align:right;
width:300px;
font-size:16px;
margin-right:-20px;
height:100px;
z-index:-100;
}
#blurb > div{
position:relative;
z-index:-100;
height:100px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="blurb">
<div>
<b style="font-size:18px;color:#EF116A;">Having problems?</b><br>
Please call our Sheffield-based support team on <b>0114 303 3232</b>.
</div>
<div>
<b style="font-size:18px;color:#EF116A;">Having problems?</b><br>
Please email our Sheffield-based support team at <b>support@ask4.com</b>.
</div>
<script>
jQuery script as above
</script>
</div>
```

(please ignore non-validation, etc, this is just an experiment)

Many thanks,

Oliver

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just FYI this question is likely getting voted down because it's a bit to ambiguous, there's no clear question being asked, and you did not include any code. Try fixing it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks adamb, have made changes now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the fade in of the nextdiv in the callback **callback function** of the fadeOut method if you want the next div to be faded in after the current animation is completed.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#blurb > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#blurb >div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000 , function() {
                 $(this).next(1).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000)
                                .end(1).appendTo('#blurb');
            })  
    }, 5000);
});
```

​

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KZr2S/)**

Comment: When you say _"You need to handle **that** ... "_ What is that?

Comment: Hi Sushanth, thanks for your answer. I put this code in, and now it is just static, with no fades. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Hi Sushanth, think you replied before I had edited by previous comment. The code you advised I used has resulted in the divs just appearing static. Could you please let me know if I have done anything wrong when changing the code over? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again. Works a treat. I have marked as accepted answer :)

Comment: @OliverSmith .. Glad to have helped :)